# Do we need to do json.dumps and encode before making a Python POST request?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

**Question 1)** Do we need to do json.dumps and encode before making a Python POST request?

Usually the request is:

```
response = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', json={'key':'value'})
```

**Question 2)**

Is it advisable to do like the below instead?:

```
x1 = {'key':'value'}
x2 = json.dumps(x1)
x3 = x2.encode()
response = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', json=x3)
```

**Question 3)** When do we need to do json.dumps and encode before making a Python POST request?

Comment: you can pass data in as `data` parameter in `response = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data={'key':"value"})` you can also set appropriate content-type in header argument as dictionary

Answer (score 1):

No, if you use the `json` parameter, it should be a dictionary. From [the documentation](https://requests.kennethreitz.org//en/master/api/#requests.request):

> json – (optional) A JSON serializable Python object to send in the body of the Request.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use **dumps** your data before making post request as given below-

```
url = "http://localhost:8080"
obj = {'City': 'Delhi', 'Country': 'India', 'message': 'Hello Team!'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(obj), headers=headers)
```

**Note:** what I've observed during testing **dumps** is not necessary in POST requests. It should also work with `data=obj` only.